# Windows API: Get micro seconds between milli seconds

Tags: c, windows, api, date, time

GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime:
Retrieves the current system date and time with the highest possible level of precision (<1us).

Which gives us a FILETIME

Then we pass it to:
FileTimeToSystemTime
Which gives us a SYSTEMTIME

But SYSTEMTIME only shows us to millisecond precision.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME, *LPSYSTEMTIME;
```

So How do I get at the (<1us) part?
I want to be able to print something like

```
printf( "milli:[%u] micro:[%u] nano:[%u]\n", 
         st.wMilliseconds, st.wMicro, st.Nano );
```

Thanks

I've tried the following:

```
int main()
{
    FILETIME ft = { 0 };
    SYSTEMTIME st = { 0 };

    UINT32 nsT = 0;
    UINT32 us = 0;
    UINT32 ns = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {

        GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&ft);

        FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);

        nsT = (ft.dwLowDateTime & 0x0FFFFFFFFLL) | (ft.dwHighDateTime << 32LL);

        us = (nsT % 10000LL) / 10LL;
        ns = (nsT % 10LL);

        wprintf(L"DT:[%u%02u%02u %02u:%02u:%02u:%03u:%03u:%u]\n",
            st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay,
            st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, st.wMilliseconds, us, ns);
    }
}
```

However it produces times that are out of order

```
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:152:735:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:164:561:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:169:126:3]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:172:595:0]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:173:428:7]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:173:415:9]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:177:446:2]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:181:309:8]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:182:386:7]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:184:650:6]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:184:740:6]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:189:271:8]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:190:471:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:194:746:6]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:197:049:5]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:198:793:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:200:823:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:200:529:1]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:202:606:3]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:210:913:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:214:764:6]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:214:815:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:219:079:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:222:580:2]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:223:959:5]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:224:933:8]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:225:844:7]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:226:810:7]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:228:811:1]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:230:139:1]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:253:539:1]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:253:653:9]
```

Note the following for a given milli(173), we have descending micros (428 to 415)  The 415 should be bigger than the  428.

```
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:173:428:7]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:173:415:9]

DT:[20190921 12:48:51:200:823:4]
DT:[20190921 12:48:51:200:529:1]
```

I then sprinted the string to a global array and printed it in subsequent loop to make sure there was no stdout race condition, but it's still out of order at a finer scale:

```
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:1]
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:3]
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:3]
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:1]
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:3]
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:1]
DT:[20190921 13:05:01:228:534:3]
```

If I add some code to compare the calculated millis vs the ST.wMilliseconds we see inconsistencies:

```
ms:[140][0x8C] != st.wMilliseconds:[177][0xB1]
ms:[284][0x11C] != st.wMilliseconds:[184][0xB8]
ms:[337][0x151] != st.wMilliseconds:[236][0xEC]
```

Following code appears to work perfectly thanks to Adrian:

```
int main()
{
    WCHAR b[MAX][256] = { 0 };

    FILETIME ft = { 0 };
    SYSTEMTIME st = { 0 };

    UINT64 ftLo = 0;
    UINT64 ftHi = 0;
    UINT64 myTime = 0;
    UINT64 ms = 0;
    UINT64 us = 0;
    UINT64 ns = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&ft);

        FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);

        ftLo = ft.dwLowDateTime;
        ftHi = ft.dwHighDateTime;
        myTime = ftLo | (ftHi << 32uLL);

        ms = (myTime % 10000000uLL) / 10000uLL;
        us = (myTime % 10000uLL) / 10uLL;
        ns = (myTime % 10uLL);

        if (ms != st.wMilliseconds)
            wprintf(L"ms:[%llu][0x%llX] != st.wMilliseconds:[%u][0x%X]\n",
                    ms, ms, st.wMilliseconds, st.wMilliseconds);

        wprintf(L"%u%02u%02u %02u:%02u:%02u:%03llu:%03llu:%llu\n",
            st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay,
            st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond,
            ms, us, ns);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
20190922 10:51:20:625:917:4
20190922 10:51:20:626:065:5
20190922 10:51:20:628:774:2
20190922 10:51:20:631:084:5
20190922 10:51:20:631:628:4
20190922 10:51:20:632:223:0
20190922 10:51:20:635:252:7
20190922 10:51:20:637:841:8
20190922 10:51:20:641:058:9
20190922 10:51:20:649:869:0
20190922 10:51:20:651:283:0
20190922 10:51:20:652:677:9
20190922 10:51:20:652:749:7
20190922 10:51:20:652:808:6
20190922 10:51:20:654:621:0
20190922 10:51:20:656:662:3
20190922 10:51:20:659:048:9
20190922 10:51:20:660:926:0
20190922 10:51:20:664:202:1
20190922 10:51:20:666:506:9
20190922 10:51:20:666:592:6
20190922 10:51:20:666:712:8
20190922 10:51:20:670:800:7
20190922 10:51:20:680:442:7
20190922 10:51:20:680:522:0
20190922 10:51:20:681:207:1
20190922 10:51:20:682:988:3
20190922 10:51:20:684:476:8
20190922 10:51:20:685:727:1
20190922 10:51:20:685:777:0
20190922 10:51:20:686:526:3
20190922 10:51:20:686:919:9
```

Comment: It is not in general sensible to interpret the returned value as absolute wall clock time.  You'd need special hardware to ensure the clock is accurate, typically done with a GPS receiver.  This function was meant as a replacement in libraries that use GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() to measure elapsed time.  The Microsoft C++ library was a notable offender in its original `<chrono>` implementation.

Comment: There could also be a problem if the `wMilliseconds` value is rounded up when the fractional part is > 0.5! But this can't account for all the 'errors' in the output list shown.

Comment: Previous comment meant, if that's how the `FileTimeToSystemTime` function works. I don't know. (Updated answer to work round that one, though!)

Comment: @HansPassant Good point! Note that the API function name has, in its name, the word,"Precise," not, "Accurate." The difference between precision and accuracy is important!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this by using a `SYSTEMTIME` structure, as you have noticed. You need to extract the data from the returned `FILETIME` structure and process that as a 64-bit integer:

```
FILETIME fTime;
GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&fTime);
uint64_t ftLo = uint64_t(fTime.dwLowDateTime);
uint64_t ftHi = uint64_t(fTime.dwHighDateTime);
uint64_t myTime = ftLo | (ftHi << 32uLL);
```

The `myTime` variable will then hold the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since 01-JAN-1601.

To get from this 'epoch' value to the 'missing' us and ns fields in `SYSTEMTIME` you can simply use the code below. You should also get your own value of milliseconds, in case the conversion to `SYSTEMTIME` has "rounded up" the `dwMilliseconds` value (don't know if this happens or not):

```
uint64_t millis = (myTime % 10000000uLL) / 10000uLL;
uint64_t micros = (myTime % 10000uLL) / 10uLL;
uint64_t nanos = (myTime % 10uLL) * 100uLL; // Will have a resolution of only 100ns
```

*(This works on the assumption that all days since 1/1/1601 have had an integral number of milliseconds, which I think is a reasonable assumption!)*

NOTE: Another option is to copy (or cast) the `FILETIME` struct to a `ULARGE_INTEGER` and then assign the `QuadPart` element of that union to `myTime`. This ***will*** also work but, *in Standard C++, writing to one part of a union and then reading from another is, formally, undefined behaviour.*

Comment: OK!  This is where I figured we would end up, I even tried similiar, but couldn't find the correct bits to mask.  How did you determine (ftLo & 0x0FFFFFFFF) was the correct mask?  THANKS!

Comment: Oh, wait a sec. I'm not asking for the "number of 100 nanosecond intervals since 01-JAN-1601" I'm asking for the number of micros between the given millis, and the number of nanos between the number of micros. Conceptually, what would be the next 2 members the SYSTEMTIME struct should have

Comment: That looks like it!  Can you explain how you determined the mask: 0x0FFFFFFFF

Comment: Please not, the results seem incorrect, question updated with source, micros are out of order

Comment: @chup - See latest edit and the comments in your original question. Still thinking, though ...

Comment: Why not just use LARGE_INTEGER when converting FILETIME to INT64?

Comment: Yes but you could remove 80% of your answer by removing the talk about sign and masks :)

Comment: @harold - Answer simplified now, by using all uint64_t variables.

Comment: The calculation for millis does not match ST.wMilliseconds  So how reliable can it be?

Comment: @chup Is the difference large or small?

Comment: Problem in your code is that you declare `nsT`, `us` and `ns` as `UINT32`! They ***must*** be 64-bit integers: `uint64_t` or the code won't work.